# Common IO - listFilesAndDirs only shows files

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm trying to use `FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs` to show all the files and folders in a given path but currently my code only gets the files and filters out the directories in the given path.

```
    //Ask for the path to the directory
    System.out.println("Enter path: ");
    path = scanner.nextLine();
    File myFile = new File(path);   

    if(myFile == null || !myFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Bad directory path!");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    //Make a filter that matches files and directories
    final IOFileFilter myFilter = new IOFileFilter() {  
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return true;

        }
    };

    //List files and folders in that directory
    Collection<File> listOfFiles = FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(myFile, myFilter, null);

    for(File file : listOfFiles) {
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.print("Directory: ");
        }
        else { 
            System.out.println("File: ");
        }

        System.out.print(file.getAbsolutePath());       
    }
```

Comment: Library has a built in filter `TrueFileFilter.TRUE`, that accepts everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take in mind that if the third param is null you wont get any folders 
you can just use :

```
//Use TrueFileFilter.TRUE to match all directories
TrueFileFilter.TRUE


FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(myFile, TrueFileFilter.TRUE, TrueFileFilter.TRUE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Given this:

```
FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(myFile, myFilter, null)
```

you need to specify the filter for directories. From [the doc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFilesAndDirs%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29):

> If this parameter is null, subdirectories will not be included in the
>   search